# Scroll programmatically a PDFView horizontally

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a PDFView with a scrollbar. I want to bind a keyboard shortcut to scroll horizontally.

For vertical scrolling I did  this

> [pdfView scrollLineUp:self]

and it works correctly.

For horizontal I tried this (and many variations) without success

> ```
> NSScrollView *scrollView = [pdfView enclosingScrollView];
> NSView *documentView = [scrollView documentView];
> NSRect point = [documentView visibleRect];
> point.origin.x -= 4.0;
> [documentView scrollRectToVisible:point]; //    [self.centerViewController.pdfView scrollRectToVisible:point];
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pdfview contains its own internal scrollview. Found on this thread http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/176723-how-do-subclass-the-nsscrollview-of-pdfview.html

Answer (score 0):

When you want to scroll the document view, you need to use the `scrollToPoint:` method. Take a look at [this Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Scrolling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003463-SW2). It contains code snippet that may help you.